# BeginForm faz GET em vez de POST

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, formulário

Tenho um controller que tem duas Actions;

```
public ActionResult Cadastrar()
{
    return View();
}


//[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Cadastrar(Usuario usuario)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var appUsuario = new UsuarioAplicacao();
        appUsuario.Salvar(usuario);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(usuario);
}
```

E tenho essa view

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Cadastrar","Usuario",FormMethod.Post)) 
{
    código código código
    <input type="submit" value="Cadastrar" class="btn_login" />
}
```

Quando eu clico em submit na página de cadastro ele vai para a mesma página enviando por get os valores do form:

> http://localhost:51497/Usuario/Cadastrar?idUsuario=&Nome=&Email=&Senha=&Permissao=

E quando isso acontece ele chama o cadastrar por get e o ciclo se repete.

Não consigo cadastrar de maneira alguma, alguém tem alguma dica?

Comment: Coloque o código html gerado!

Comment: Melhor, https://github.com/marks5/meurepo_forsoft2/blob/testes/Forsoft2_tentativa6/Forsoft2_tentativa6/Views/Usuario/Cadastrar.cshtml

Comment: estou achando estranho isso, porque o código está certo, eu queria na verdade, o código gerado pelo navegador, o html puro, clicando com o botão direito **exibir código da página**, quero entender a geração

Comment: Eu passei a tarde codando e encontrei o problema. A causa do problema era um aninhamento de formulários. Inclusive depois adiciono uma resposta com pesquisas que fiz. Como eu diz um renderbody dentro de um template que a equipe de frontend me passou acabou que despercebido o form anterior, então sempre que o beginform fazia o post ele subia de hierarquia. E bem, gerava o Get. Agradeço sua disponibilidade para me ajudar. :-)